# Domain based TCP and UDP Routing in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, tcp, udp, kubernetes-ingress

I have a Kubernetes cluster with an on-demand auto-scaler to provide easily scaleable VM instances.

I want to provide SSH access (port 22) to the machines created within them behind a single ingress controller.

Example:

```
ssh poda.example.com:22 it should provide an ssh connection to pod A
ssh podb.example.com:22 it should provide an ssh connection to pod B
```

Another Example of UDP: There are two deployments of Redis within the cluster in two different namespaces. within the cluster, we are able to separate them using their service name. but outside the cluster we are not able to separate them

Expected Behaviour

```
redis-staging.example.com:6379 should connect to Redis in staging namespace
redis-prod.example.com:6379 it should connect to Redis in production namespace
```

I was using the Nginx ingress controller to open the port via a load-balancer to provide ssh access using the https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/ documentation.

Challenge is that this directly bypasses the requirement of the sub-domain part and connects one port to one pod only. even a non-existing sub-domain can connect to the one pod linked to the port exposed.

How can I implement the desired behavior with Nginx or any other Ingress controller?

Comment: Has your issue been resolved?If yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as a solution and accept it?